Mongodb iterative methods inside aggregate pipeline
Hi so I am working on a database and we have 100k entries where the structure looks similar to
dict = {
        'testResults': {
                     'test_1':1, #1 or 0 if a test passed/failed respectively
                     'test_2':0,
                     'test_3':1,
                      ....,
                     'test_N':1,
                    },
}

so far i have an aggregate pipline like:
result = list(mycol.aggregate([
        {
            "$group": {
                '_id': f'{testname}',
                'pass': {"$sum":f"$individual_test_outcomes.{testname}"},
                'count': {"$sum":1},
            },
            
        },
        {
          "$addFields":{
                'passRate': {"$divide":["$pass","$count"]},
            },  
        }
    ]))

and this gives me the number of how many files passed a particular test,  the total number of files, and the pass rate.
This gives me an output like
{
 '_id': 'test_1',
 'pass': 50,
 'count':100,
 'rate':0.5
}

but there are many tests besides test one, so I want an output that is like:
{
{
 '_id': 'test_1',
 'pass': 50,
 'count':100,
 'rate':0.5
}, 
{
 '_id': 'test_2',
 'pass': 50,
 'count':100,
 'rate':0.5
},
...
{
 '_id': 'test_N',
 'pass': 50,
 'count':100,
 'rate':0.5
}
}

my solution was to write a function and pass all the test names into a for loop and appending the results, but I am worried that this will be too slow and inefficient.
I was wondering if anyone knew how to write an iterative method in the aggregate to achieve the desired results

Can you please explain the logic (which matches the sample input data)? For me it is not clear at all what you are looking for.

So from my current aggregate pipeline, it can output the quantities I desire for a single test in the data file. For instance in the sample, this gives me the total number of data files that pass test_1, the total number of data files, and the pass rate. I was wondering if there was an aggregate scheme such that instead of returning those fields for one test, it would return those fields over all tests in the test_result dictionary

You may want to have a look at "$objectToArray" and "$unwind" before "$group".
